# Apply gradient on a UIView not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, quartz-core, cagradientlayer

I am trying to add gradient to a UIView programmatically but it is not working. It just appears to have no color at all. I have attached the relevant code as well as a screenshot. Notice the bottom square over which i am applying the gradient. Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here?

[image: Screenshot]

```
let sundayView = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupViews()
    setupSundayView()
}

func setupViews() {
    sundayView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(sundayView)
}

func setupSundayView() {
    sundayView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
        sundayView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerXAnchor),
        sundayView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(fridayView.bottomAnchor, constant: 16.0),
        sundayView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),            
        sundayView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(mondayView.heightAnchor),
        sundayView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(mondayView.widthAnchor)
        ])

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = sundayView.bounds
    gradient.colors = [
        UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.37, blue:0.23, alpha:1.0).CGColor,
        UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.16, blue:0.41, alpha:1.0).CGColor
    ]
    sundayView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
}
```

Comment: Did not you forget to import `QuartzCore` framework?

Comment: I guess its not necessary. I tried applying gradient to my superview. It worked without importing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your gradient isn't showing because the `bounds` for `sundayView` will not be set until *Auto Layout* runs.  Override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and set the gradient frame there.

Add this property to your viewController:

```
var sundayGradient: CAGradientLayer?
```

In `setupSundayView` save the `gradient` to the property:

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
sundayGradient = gradient
```

Then set the frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    sundayGradient?.frame = sundayView.bounds
}
```

Comment: Ummm.. Sorry, I am having trouble understanding _Set the gradient to it_ code. Please, can you please explain again? :)

Comment: in `setupSundayView` after the line `let gradient = CAGradientLayer()` add the line `sundayGradient = gradient`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked :) But it is breaking another line of code i added: `sundayView.layer.cornerRadius = 5` .

Comment: set `sundayView.clipsToBounds = true`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you forgot to add `locations` to gradient layer, try it like this:

```
func setupSundayView() {
    sundayView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
        sundayView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerXAnchor),
        sundayView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(fridayView.bottomAnchor, constant: 16.0),
        sundayView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),            
        sundayView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(mondayView.heightAnchor),
        sundayView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(mondayView.widthAnchor)
        ])

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = sundayView.bounds
    gradient.colors = [
        UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.37, blue:0.23, alpha:1.0).CGColor,
        UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.16, blue:0.41, alpha:1.0).CGColor
    ]
    gradient.locations = [0.0, 0.5]
    sundayView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
}
```

Comment: Ok, in your `viewDidLoad` try to call `setupSundayView()` function before `setupViews()`.

Comment: It is the sundayView frames. I tried adding sundayView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 130, height: 130)
It worked.

Comment: But that is overriding my heightAnchor and widthAnchor now. Is there any way by which initialize frame without defining size?