# Horizontal Gradient colour Showing Half only in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, colors, gradient

I I am trying to give the Gradient color for Button Baground, I am trying with following code

```
func setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor, colorTwo: UIColor) {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorOne.cgColor, colorTwo.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }

@IBOutlet weak var loginbtn: UIButton!
loginbtn.setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor.red, colorTwo: UIColor.blue)
```

I am trying to access this method it will show the output like this How to we fix this, [image: See output]

If I add following code

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        loginbtn.setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor.red, colorTwo: UIColor.green)
    }
```

it will show the following error.
[image: Image like as joint]

Comment: See: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38411237/1630618)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are setting the gradient frame ***after*** auto-layout has set the size of the button.

If you subclass the button, you can do so in `layoutSubviews()`.

Otherwise, A good place to do this in your view controller is in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    loginbtn.setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor.red, colorTwo: UIColor.blue)
}
```

---

**Edit**

Based on the second image you posted - getting over-lapping gradients when called from `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`... As auto-layout "does its thing," that can be called more than once, and you are ***adding a new layer*** each time that is called.

I don't know what else you might be doing in your custom class, but give it a try like this:

```
class GradButton: UIButton {

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]

        // top-right to bottom-left
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)

        // we only add the layer once, here when called from init    
        layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

    }

    func setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor, colorTwo: UIColor) {
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorOne.cgColor, colorTwo.cgColor]
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    }

}

class MyTest: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var loginbtn: GradButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loginbtn.setGradientBackground(colorOne: .red, colorTwo: .yellow)
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Your code is working but in ending part it shows like as a joint